# Data bind click event not working on the <option> Html tag

Tags: data-binding, knockout.js, click, html-select

i have created the drop down using  and  tags. and
Am trying to bind the function in  tag using KO. but its not working. if i call the same function in  button or div tag its working fine, but in the option tag its not working. Any one please help me
My sample code is

```
 <form class="class1">
                <select id="id1">
                        <option value="value1" data-bind="click: function () { $parent.DeviceViewModel.info_tab1($data) }">dummy1</option>
                        <option value="value2" data-bind="click: function () { $parent.DeviceViewModel.info_tab2($data) }">dummy2</option>
                        <option value="value3" data-bind="click: function () { $parent.DeviceViewModel.info_tab3($data) }">dummy3</option>
                        <option value="value4" data-bind="click: function () { $parent.DeviceViewModel.info_tab4($data) }">dummy4</option>
                 </select>
            </form>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is because of $data used.

try using following

```
<option value="value1" data-bind="click: function () { $parent.DeviceViewModel.info_tab1($parent) }">dummy1</option>
```